# Is it possible to make a CSRF attack against an endpoint that accepts multipart/form-data (without CORS)?

Tags: security, http, csrf

Is it possible to make a browser-based [cross-site request forgery](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)) (CSRF) attack against a form/endpoint that accepts `multipart/form-data`?

I've seen several blog posts that indicate it is possible, but they are out-of-date (like [this one](http://www.gnucitizen.org/blog/cross-site-file-upload-attacks/) from 2008) or [rely on CORS being enabled](http://gerionsecurity.com/2013/04/here-it-is-the-file-upload-csrf/) (in which case CSRF tokens are redundant).

What is the definitive answer on this?

Comment: What CSRF has to do with CORS?

Comment: @cezarypiatek Enabling CORS headers can open your APIs to types of CSRF attacks.

Comment: Why did this question get downvoted? Stackoverflow is such a sewer.